# WebAsyst. Редактирование файла вывода продуктов

Tags: html

Основной шаблон стоит `aqua`.
Иду в путь `/published/SC/html/scripts/repo_themes/aqua`
меняю файл `product_info.html`, но ничего не происходит, т.е. ничего не изменяется. 
Также скачал в этой же папке файл `index.php`, но он отличается от кода, который лежит в визуальном редакторе шаблонов.

Где найти правильный файл `product_info.html`?

Comment: А вы проверяли, после изменения product_info.html и сохранения, этот файл точно изменяется? Прав доступа на изменение достаточно?

Comment: изменяется. 777 поставил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/published/publicdata/ИМЯ_ВАШЕЙ_БАЗЫ/attachments/SC/themes/ИМЯ_ВАШЕЙ_ТЕМЫ` - это для файлов главной страницы и страницы продукта.
Искать тут надо было.

Comment: Советую автора вопроса так же обратиться в "[Базу знаний WebAsyst](http://www.webasyst.ru/support/help/webasyst-shop-script.html)", она хоть и организована неудобно, но найти нужную информацию можно.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в кешировании, посмотрите настройки в админке + сбросьте кеш в инсталлере. если не поможет проблема с правами доступа к файлам